# Fading acne-hyperpigmentation

Tags: acne, topical-cream-gel, coloration-discoloration, blemishes, hyperpigmentation

So I've been on diffren (adapalene gel) and it's really helped with my stubborn acne.

However, I now have acne hyperpigmentation (the red spots on my skin).  I've been trying to find an over the counter medicine, and have come across this: http://www.kiehls.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-kiehls_us-Site/en_US/Link-Product?pid=595

It's a retinol  booster- so will it help with my hyperpigmentation?

Thanks!